# Qartz regex accepts cron but won't builds a job from it

Tags: java, regex, scala, cron, quartz-scheduler

Checking cron: "0 0 * * * *" to regex from job_scheduling_data-1_8.xsd of quartz lib returns true:

```
scala> "0 0 * * * *".matches("""(((([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]),)*([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))|(([\*]|[0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(/|-)([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))|([\?])|([\*]))[\s](((([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]),)*([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))|(([\*]|[0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(/|-)([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))|([\?])|([\*]))[\s](((([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]),)*([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))|(([\*]|[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(/|-)([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))|([\?])|([\*]))[\s](((([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]),)*([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(C)?)|(([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(/|-)([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(C)?)|(L)|(LW)|([1-9]W)|([1-3][0-9]W)|([\?])|([\*]))[\s](((([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]),)*([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])(/|-)([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC),)*(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))|((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(-|/)(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))|([\?])|([\*]))[\s]((([1-7],)*([1-7]))|([1-7](/|-)([1-7]))|(((MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN),)*(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(C)?)|((MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(-|/)(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(C)?)|(([1-7]|(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(L|LW)?)|(([1-7]|MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)#([1-7])?)|([\?])|([\*]))([\s]?(([\*])?|(19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9]))?| (((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9]))(-|/)((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])))?| ((((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])),)*((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])))?)""")
res7: Boolean = true
```

But when I try to schedule the job with that cron I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '0 0 * * * *' is invalid.
at org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.java:111)
```

How can I validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to Quartz - you can use built-in functionality like:

```
org.quartz.CronExpression.isValidExpression(String cronExpression);
```

More info: [Quartz-javadoc]

- http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html#isValidExpression%28java.lang.String%29
- http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/